# data parsing using c++

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

```
.i 8
.o 8
.ilb a b c d e f g h
.ob a b c d e f g h
00000000 00000000
00000001 00000011
................
................
.e
```

I tried the code like this. there are no compilation errors

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Line12.hpp"
#include "Line34.hpp"
#include "Line261.hpp"

using namespace std;
void printLine12(Line12 line1)
{ 
    cout << "first:" << line1.getFirst() << endl;
    cout << "in:" << line1.getIn() << endl;       
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<Line12> lines12;
    std::vector<Line34> lines34;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::bitset<8> > > a;
    std::vector<Line261> lines261;

    std::ifstream in("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/hwb8_64.pla");
    std::string Line;

    for(int i=1; i<=261;i++)
    {
        std::getline(in,Line);
        if(i==1 || i==2)
        {
            Line12 s(Line);
            lines12.push_back(s);
        }
        else if(i==3 || i==4)
        {
            Line34 s1(Line);
            lines34.push_back(s1);
        }
        else if(i==261)
        {
            Line261 s2(Line);
            lines261.push_back(s2);
        }
        else
        {
            a.push_back(std::vector< std::bitset<8> >());
            std::istringstream iss(Line);
            std::string bits;
            while (iss >> bits)
            {
                a.back().push_back(std::bitset<8>(bits));
            }

        }

    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    for(int i=1; i<=261;i++)
    {
        if(i==1 || i==2)
        {
            Line12 s1 = lines12.at(i);
            printLine12(s1);
        } 
        else if(i==3 || i==4)
        {
            Line34 s2 = lines34.at(i);
            printLine34(s2);
        }
        else if(i==261)
        {
            Line261 s3 = lines261.at(i);
            printLine261(s3);
        }    
        else
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < a.size(); ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < a[i].size(); ++y)
                {
                    for (int z = 7; z >= 0; --z)
                    {
                        std::cout << a[x][y][z];
                    }
                    std::cout << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }      
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

but when I run the code. it shows like this.What should I do to rectify this.

```
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'

  what<>:  bitset::_M_copy from ptr
```

what should I do rectify this error and get the output.

Answer (score 1):

The `bitset` constructor takes a `string` of ones and zeroes. It throws an `invalid_argument` exception if you pass something that's not ones and zeroes. You did pass something that was not only ones and zeros and here you are.

Please do some basic debugging yourself to verify your program is working correctly before posting here.

Comment: Can I Know were I went wrong in the code. I did pass a string bits to the `bitset`.

Comment: @user3898956 No, you did not. Or did you debug it? Do you *know* what characters are in this string? Your computer says it's not only 1s and 0s. And I trust in your computer more than I trust your ability to somehow *sense* what *might* have happened. Learn to use a debugger. Using a debugger properly will solve this and a lot of your future problems.